# Blank ListPlot with a table

Tags: plotting

I generated 2 .dat files with 1000 data points separately, imported as Table and flatten them, then combined and formed a Table for ListPlot. But it gives me a blank plot and I don't know why.

Here's the full code:

```
SetDirectory["E:\\work\\ST\\works\\sim"];
a = OpenWrite["a0_sim.dat"];
p = OpenWrite["p_sim.dat"];

bmax[\[Theta]w_] := (1.14*10^9)/Sin[\[Theta]w/2]^(9/7);
db[\[Theta]w_] := bmax[\[Theta]w]/10^5;
Pb[\[Theta]w_, b_] := (2 b db[\[Theta]w])/bmax[\[Theta]w]^2;        
a0[\[Theta]w_, b_] := (9*10^10)/((2.5*10^63)/(Sin[\[Theta]w/2]^7 b^7)-Sin[\[Theta]w/2]^2); 

n = 10^3;
m = 0;
While[m < n, {\[Theta]w = \[Pi] Random[];
               b = bmax[\[Theta]w] Random[];
               Write[a, a0[\[Theta]w, b]];
               Write[p, Pb[\[Theta]w, b]];
               m++}
     ]
Close[a];
Close[p];
ain = Flatten@Import["a0_sim.dat"];
pin = Flatten@Import["p_sim.dat"];
ap = Table[{ain[[i]], pin[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@ain}];
ListPlot[ap]
```

And what my table prints like:
[image]

This is really troubling me and thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Please show the `ListPlot` command you used.  Display all code and data in Mathematica format, not as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Mathematica way of achieving that:

```
bmax[θw_] := (1.14*10^9)/Sin[θw/2]^(9/7);   
db[θw_] := bmax[θw]/10^5;
Pb[θw_, b_] := (2 b db[θw])/bmax[θw]^2;
a0[θw_, b_] := (9*10^10)/((2.5*10^63)/(Sin[θw/2]^7 b^7)-Sin[θw/2]^2);
ap = Table[
   θw = π Random[];
   b = bmax[θw] Random[];
   {a0[θw, b], Pb[θw, b]}
   , {m, 0, 10^3}];
ListPlot[ap]
```

[image]

If in addition you want to export the files, use [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html).

Comment: Thanks so much! That does the job so tidy. So does my problem occurs because my coding complicates things? But where is the problem exactly, if I may ask?

Comment: I didn't bother to look for the mistake. The advantage of doing things in the "natural" way is that things are "automatically" fine and you avoid having to solve problems that simply don't occur in the first place. I'd recommend going over [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) to get some basic Mathematica practices.